# Why does the authentication for Twitter's API stops working after X runs

Tags: python, twitter, postman, twitter-oauth

I've had this weird issue with Twitter's API.

When I run my Python code, the Twitter API works fine at retrieving recent tweets. However, after some runs, I get a 401 error.

After I get the 401 error, I then test the API in Postman. This runs successfully (which indicates that I haven't encountered a rate limit).

I then copy the Authentication code from Postman into my code editor, and then my program works again--until the authentication stops working for some reason and I have to repeat the above process!

I'm not sure what's happening. Does Postman update the Authentication code after some calls to the API?

Comment: May be try adding delay between requests

Comment: I run the code every hour.

Comment: which api endpoint are you using ,

Comment: Recent search. See: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/tweets/search/api-reference/get-tweets-search-recent

I'm not hitting rate limits, I don't think. As well, my Developer account says I have lots of requests available for this month. I request 100 tweets per hour.

Comment: Is the only error, HTTP 401 - are you seeing any API error response?